# code for pruning a binary tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

I am trying to write a code for removing the leaves of a tree and printing the rest of tree.

I am able to get proper output in case of a balanced tree. for example

```
              1
             / \
            2   3
           / \    \
          4  5     6
```

The output of this tree must be 213 (when printed inorder)

some how I am not getting desired output when it is a unbalanced tree. for ex

```
              1
             / \
            2   3
           / \    \
          4  5     6
         / \
        7   8
```

I am getting  `4 3 2 5 1 3. which is wrong.`

```
correct answer is 4 2 1 3.(printed inorder)
```

Can somebody help me what mistake I am making?

The code for the program is

```
    //prune a tree


    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    struct Node{
        int data;
        struct Node *left;
        struct Node *right;
    };

    struct Node *follower=NULL;
    struct Node *create_node(int item)
    {
        struct Node *newNode=NULL;
        newNode= new Node;
        newNode->data=item;
        newNode->left=NULL;
        newNode->right=NULL;

        return newNode;
    }

    void extract_leaves_binary_tree(struct Node *root)
    {
        int na=0;
        if(root==NULL)
        return;

        if(root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL)
        {
            na=1;
        }   
        else
        {
            follower=root;
        }

        if(na==1 )
        {       
            if(follower->left==root)
                follower->left=NULL;            
            if(follower->right==root)
                follower->right=NULL;                   
            na=0;
        }   
        extract_leaves_binary_tree(root->left);
        extract_leaves_binary_tree(root->right);

    }


    void print(struct Node *root)
    {
        if(root==NULL)
        return;

        print(root->left);
        cout<<root->data;
        print(root->right);
    }

    void driver(struct Node *root)
    {

        extract_leaves_binary_tree(root);

    }

    int main()
    {
        struct Node *root=NULL;
        root  = create_node(1);
         root->left = create_node(2);
         root->right = create_node(3);
         root->left->left = create_node(4);
         root->left->right = create_node(5);
         root->right->right = create_node(6);
         root->left->left->left = create_node(7);
        root->left->left->right = create_node(8);

        driver(root);
        cout<<"inordrer"<<endl;
        print(root);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: There is no language called "C/C++". Your code is obviously C++. Removed "c/c++" from title and removed C tag.

Comment: @slim - that method is there. And he's removing all the leaf nodes.

Comment: You are using a global variable. This is your problem right here. Do. Not. Use. Globals.

Comment: I tried declaring it inside. I am getting segmentation fault.

Comment: This is not an excuse to use a global. Nothing is. Try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head I think it would be a lot simpler to do something like this:

```
Node* internal_extract_leaves(struct Node* root)
{
  if(root == NULL)
    return NULL;

  if(root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL)
    return NULL;

  root->left = internal_extract_leaves(root->left);
  root->right = internal_extract_leaves(root->right);  

  return root;
}

void extract_leaves_binary_tree(struct Node *root)
{
  root = internal_extract_leaves(root);
}
```

Comment: is there a missing `return root` at the end of `internal_extract_leaves()`?

Comment: return type for the function is Node* , but where are you returning the root?

Answer (score 1):

Line `if(root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL)` checks if both child are `NULL` however element *2* has only one of them `NULL` so its skipped and element *5* never gets removed. Same for element *3* on the right side. You need to do individual check for each side.

Edit: Above information is wrong. The problem is that follower is a global
 so you change it and when you go back to node 2 from your left recursion to go recurse the right side follower is no longer node 2. Which means you can't delete it.

Comment: Can't write code on mobile so I thought I should atleast point out the mistake.

Comment: Element 3 also has one of them , but 6 will be removed.

Comment: Because 6 obviously has no children it gets removed.

Comment: Just fixed my answer sorry the if's are not the problem the global is. I really should stop answering questions while outside.

Comment: I tried declaring my follower pointer inside, but I get segmentation fault.

Comment: If my return type is void in the function extract_leaves_binary_tree(). the I should be sending my root pointer by reference . Is this right? I mean my function call must will look like                                                            """void extract_leaves_binary_tree(struct Node **root)""".  Only then I will be able to print nodes after pruning the leaves.

Comment: No you are actually passing the pointer to the node to the function so your current call is fine.

Comment: But how will I print the pruned tree?

Comment: As you are actually modifying the tree and not a duplicate you can just print it like you would print any tree. Recurse over it in order.

Comment: Can you share your code. I am getting getting segmentation fault if I declare struct Node* follower inside the function

Comment: You should write the answer to it yourself and mark it correct or accept one of the current answers as correct

Answer (score 1):

I must admit I can't make much sense of the algorithm you've tried here. I guess I'm confused because I don't know what you mean by `following` or `na`, and because you refer to every node as `root`. And, by using a global variable, you've given me a layer of complexity I don't want to think about.

And if I don't understand your intent, then neither will you when you return to your own code 6 months down the line.

It can help to create functions with explanatory names, like `isLeaf()` here. This is a technique called "functional decomposition" -- make an algorithm easier to understand by breaking it into smaller functions. Functional decomposition also tends to result in more efficient code because it gives optimising compilers more structure to work with.

I think the code below is as self-explanatory as recursive code can be:

- if the child exists...

  - ... and it's a leaf, delete it
  - ... else it's not a leaf: recurse into it

---

```
 bool isLeaf(struct Node* node) {
      // assumes we will never be passed NULL. 
      return (node->left == NULL) && (node->right == NULL);
 }

 void remove_leaves(struct Node* node) {
    // assumes we will never be passed NULL. Certainly never passes itself NULL!
    if(node->left != NULL) {
       if(isLeaf(node->left)) {
          node->left = NULL;
       } else {
          remove_leaves(node->left);
       }
    }
    if(node->right != NULL) {
       if(isLeaf(node->right)) {
          node->right = NULL;
       } else {
          remove_leaves(node->right);
       }
    }
 }

 int main() {
      struct Node *root=create_node(1);
      // create tree as before
      remove_leaves(root);
      print(root);
 }
```

---

Alternatively (prompted by the comments below) you could copy the tree, omitting leaves:

- Create a new node with the same data as the source
- If the child of the source exists and is not a leaf, create a copy of the child and make that the child of your copy.

---

```
struct Node* copy_minus_leaves(struct Node *node) {
    // assume we are never passed NULL
    struct Node* copy = create_node(node->data);

    if(node->left != NULL && !isLeaf(node->left)) {
        copy->left = copy_minus_leaves(node->left);
    }

    if(node->right!= NULL && !isLeaf(node->right)) {
        copy->right= copy_minus_leaves(node->right);
    }

    return copy;
}

int main() {
    struct Node *root=create_node(1);
    // create tree as before
    struct Node *copy = copy_minus_leaves(root);
    print(copy);
 }
```

---

Note that neither of these algorithms will remove the root of the tree, even if it is a leaf (i.e. the tree contains only one node). That may or may not be desirable, depending on what you're using the tree for. You would need to treat a zero-node tree as a special case.

Note also that this code doesn't `free()` the memory allocated to the deleted leaves. Rather than clutter the code, I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

You tend to know when you've got recursive code right, because it suddenly looks very simple.

Comment: are you passing it NULL?

Comment: @slim  I am not passing NULL

Comment: if you are not returning anything. Then How can how do you print the pruned tree?

Comment: It modifies the tree in place. You could write a function which returns a copy of the tree, minus leaves -- `struct Node* copy = copy_without_leaves(root); print(copy);` but that is not what your original code attempted.

Comment: How do I check whether it is pruning it or not. one way I can do is through printing it. If you dont return the root for pruned tree, how will we check?

Comment: See example main() I added.

Comment: I think it will print all the nodes in the original tree not pruned.Other wise we have to pass root pointer by reference

Comment: You are passing it a reference. `(struct Node* node)`. At some point you modify the tree, with `node->left = NULL`. So the leaf has been removed.